# Automatically generate document in Salesforce on insert operation in custom object

Tags: salesforce

I am new to Salesforce.
I have a custom object named Property.

On insertion of record in the Property object I want to generate a document automatically and fill up the Property related record data in the same.
When editing the added record the document must be found in the Related tab which can be viewed/downloaded.

1. Where can I create the letter templates ?
2. How will the letter templates invoked for filling data related to Property in it ?
3. How will the document generation process be carried out automatically on insert operation in Property object ?

Thank you in advance for help.
Detailed steps to achieve above will be appreciated.